# Bad practice ? More than one WebView to implement a multiple tabs browser

Tags: android, android-webview, chromium

I've been developing a simple customized browser using Android WebView for a period of time. Recently I'm facing a choice to make the browser support multiple tabs. The first option is to instantiate one more Android WebView, and the second option is to break what I've built using the WebView and fork Open-sourced Chromium project then transfer it into my customized browser from scratch.

However, the second approach isn't easy. So my main question is, **is instantiating multiple WebViews for multiple tabs a quite bad practice?** Does this approach eat much more memory usage than what we expect?

Comment: I'd consider a 3rd approach-  keep track of what the tabs hold, and load it from the web on tab switch, so you only need 1 webview.  Or if that's too network/time intensive, cache it to disk on first request and load it from the cache.

Comment: @GabeSechan, but some data like user input is cleared after loading web page from cache, isn't it ?

Comment: Probably.  A big part of this is you're really trying to do this at the wrong level.  A normal browser has multiple tabs, but it doesn't save every view/window/widget on screen.  It stores a parse tree of the html and renders that.  As such, it can quickly render, without taking the memory of a full set of views.  With multiple WebViews you won't have that option, as there's no way to tell it to reduce memory usage.  My guess is you can get away with a few tabs, but as the site complexity and number increase you will run OOM on many devices.

Comment: Of course the best way to tell is to measure-  put 2 bunch of webviews in a viewpager or tab layout.  Measure the memory taken.  Then add a 3rd.  Remeasure.  The delta is the cost of a tab.  If its in the few meg range, you're like ok for a few tabs.  If its tens of megs, you likely have issues.  It shouldn't take more than an hour or so to test.

Comment: @GabeSechan, I got it. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I extended my customized browser with multiple WebViews support which restricts users to create limited tabs. I also find the WebView is lightweight enough. The memory increases roughly 4 MB in average per new WebView loading an URL. Also, the YouTube can't be played simultaneously with multiple tabs. The last played YouTube will pause the previous one.